# Add symbol to string c#

Tags: c#, string, symbols

I apologize for this simple question (probably), but I am looking for a way to add the symbol "\" to a string.

here's what i need:

```
string a = "Name\Name"
```

I need it for build INI file and add this line (I know how to build new file)

How should i do that?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I'm getting error on the "\" - unrecognized escape sequence

Answer (score 6):

`\` is the escape character - in order to display it you need to escape the `\` - the "unable to recognise escape sequence" issue is because the compiler thinks you are trying to escape the characters after the backslash.

```
string a = "Name\\Name"
```

Alternatively you can use a string literal:

```
string a = @"Name\Name"
```

Comment: what is the reason for the downvote? as far as i'm aware the answer is correct.

Answer (score 4):

Alternative syntax:

```
string a = @"Name\Name";
```

Comment: Ohh!!! Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 3):

If you add an `@` sign to your string, you will change the escape behavior of the slash so it will be output "as-is". This is known as a verbatim string literal.

> Verbatim string literals start with @ and are also enclosed in double
>   quotation marks.

```
string a = @"Name\Name";
```

See the [string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) documentation on MSDN.